# How to translate the word "lost"/"loss" into Klingon?

Tags: klingon, translation

Say for instance I want to say something like, "I'm looking for bears and the lost sheep." I would think that would be to use the genitive case, making something like:

> `mIl'oDmey chIlpu'ghach       DI'raqmey   je  vInejtaH`
>   `bear-<pl> lose-<perf>-<nom>  sheep-<pl>  too <I-them>-look for-<continuous>`

But that looks kind of odd, and I've heard that using the nominalizer suffix "-ghach" is often discouraged, and should replaced by using sentences as objects if possible. Would

> `mIl'oDmey DI'raqmey   'e'  chIlpu'     je  vInejtaH`
>   `bear-<pl> sheep-<pl>  that lose-<perf> and <I-them>-look for-<continuous>`

work and make more sense?

Also, how would "I can bear the loss of sheep." be translated? My first guess would be to just reverse the noun-noun-construction so that "DI'raqmey" is the genitive noun:

> `DI'raqmey   chIlpu'ghach      vISIQlaH`
>   `sheep-<pl>  lose-<perf>-<nom> <I-it>-endure/bear-<ability>`

Would some sort of subclause make more sense here too? Just the same one?:

> `DI'raqmey    'e'  chIlpu'     vISIQlaH`
>   `sheep-<pl>   that lose-<perf> <I-it>-endure/bear-<ability>`

Comment: You might want to visit the [Klingon Language Institute](https://www,kli.org), who maintain much material on the tlhIngan-Hol. Among their resources, they maintain a mailing list where one may discuss anything in tlhIngan-Hol, or tlhIngan-Hol in English.

Answer (score 2):

1. I would translate it as *I am looking for bears and I am looking for the sheep that are lost.* — I don't know the word for *sheep*, so I assume from your question that it's **DI'raq**:

> `mIl'oDmey vInejtaH                 'ej DI'raqmey  chIlpu'bogh       vInejtaH`
>   `bear-<pl> <I-them>-look for-<cont> and sheep-<pl> lose-<perf>-<rel> <I-them>-look for-<cont>`

See: Klingon Dictionary 6.2 (*Complex Sentences*) and 6.2.3 (*Relative Clauses*)

2. Your second sentence, *I can bear the loss of sheep.* — I would opt for a subordinate clause, *If I lose sheep, I can bear it.*:

> `DI'raqmey  vIchIlpu'chugh          vISIQlaH`
>   `sheep-<pl> <I-them>-lose-<perf>-if <I-it>-bear/endure-<ability>`

See: Klingon Dictionary 6.2.2 (*Subordinate Clauses*)

Disclaimer: I'm not a Klingon expert, so this might not be 100% accurate.